# Draw Circle where user clicks with UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am new to swift. I want to draw Circle on those pixels where user clicks.
 Here is my code it is drawing circle but not at where I clicks....
I want to draw circle where user clicks....Like it is getting the coordinates where user clicks and printing them to console but I want to update the x and y arguments in ovalsandcircles() function.

Thanks in advance.

```
`import UIKit

class DemoView: UIView {

    var startX :CGFloat = 0.0
    var startY :CGFloat = 0.0
    var path: UIBezierPath!

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

     self.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }



    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // Specify the fill color and apply it to the path.
        ovalsAndCircles()
        UIColor.orange.setFill()
        path.fill()

        Specify a border (stroke) color.
        UIColor.purple.setStroke()
        path.stroke()

    }

    func ovalsAndCircles () {
        self.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: startX,
                                                y: startY,
                                                width: 200,
                                                height: 200))

    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let point = touches.first!.location(in: self)
        startX = point.x
        startY = point.y
        print(startY)
        print(startX)


    }

}
`
```

Comment: Well, technically you only need to force redraw, that is, call `setNeedsDisplay`. That should make your `draw` be called again and path recreated with your new origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Add a UIView control through Interface Builder.

(2) Set the class name of that `UIView` control to `DemoView`.

(3) Create a subclass of `UIView` as `DemoView` as follows.

```
import UIKit

class DemoView: UIView {
    let fillColor = UIColor.green
    let strokeColor = UIColor.black
    let radius: CGFloat = 100.0

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = event?.allTouches?.first
        if let touchPoint = touch?.location(in: self) {
            drawCircle(point: touchPoint)
        }
    }

    func drawCircle(point: CGPoint) {
        if let subLayers = self.layer.sublayers {
            for subLayer in subLayers {
                subLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            }
        }

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: point, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2.0), clockwise: true)
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = fillColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: That sublayer is not really necessary, you could just use the `draw` function.

Comment: @Sulthan That's true.  It's just one way of doing it.

Comment: For efficiency reasons it is not nice to recreate the layer all the time. It's unnecessary. And it's not a good idea to remove all sublayers because this way you would break subviews for example.

Answer (score 0):

First look at the Coordinate System in iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html

The `CGRect` has a origin property of type `CGPoint`. Maybe it helps to set the origin of your rect in your `draw` function:

```
let rect: CGRect = .... 
rect.origin = CGPoint(x:0.5, y:0.5) //Set the origin to the middle of the rect
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the `touchesBegan` Method to set the points where it should be drawn. But when the user moves over the screen it wont be recognized. Use `touchesEnded` Method instead